# Displacement node not working as expected

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, displacement

I'm learning displacement node setups and I can't seem to get it to work properly. The height map seems not to be in sync with the rest of the maps, although I've checked with node wrangler that all maps are in the right place and overlaying without shifting.

I've plugged the Height map into a displacement node  with the color output in the displacement height input.

The material settings are set to displace only. All maps are connected to a mapping node and have the same coordinates. The model is UV unwrapped properly. The edges of the model are mean creased to full 1.0. I'm using cycles with GPU compute.

**Q:** Anyone know where this shift in displacement comes from?

**Q:** And as a bonus, how to make the displacement look better? I've subdivided the plane 30*30 and added a Subsurf modifier in setting 4 and it still looks jagged.

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Node setup]

[image: Viewport]

[image: Viewport render]

Texture settings:

[image: Texture settings]

Comment: In order to get displacement working, your model needs to have much, **much** more subdivisions.

Comment: subsurf modifier too might help

Answer (score 1):

On the Height Node:
- Change the space color on the height map from sRGB to non-color